# 3D plot from model in R plotly?

Tags: r, 3d, regression, plotly, r-plotly

Is it possible to generate a 3D plot from models using plotly? I tried to search over the internet, but many examples are based on the infamous volcano dataset that generates a plot from a matrix of points.

My two models are:

> y = 0.49867x - 4.78577
>
> y = 76.13084x + 4.81945

If not possible, how can i transform my data into the matrix format such as that in the volcano dataset? For more details, I have hosted the data file [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=00474804378576763014&t=0047480437857676301457047). I have never used plotly before and i'm unfamiliar with the grammar, but i think i can manage if i can at least format my data into the likes of the volcano dataset.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To plot a surface with plotly, you need to construct a numeric matrix.

Taking [Himmelblau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himmelblau%27s_function) as a test:

```
f <- function(x, y) { (x^2+y-11)^2 + (x+y^2-7)^2 }
```

Create *x* and *y* values:

```
x <- seq(-6, 6, length = 100)
y <- x
```

Then, create *z* with `outer` function. It will return a matrix.

```
z <- outer(x, y, f)
```

We can now create a surface plot:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = ~z) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]